# What is the meaning of りゃ in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, usage, contractions

I came across this phrase while reading an interview.

> そういう時はなんて答え**りゃ**いいんだ。

I think it means "At a time like that, such a reply/response is good."

But I don't understand the usage of りゃ. I couldn't find any reference as a suffix or conjugation.

Comment: Snailboat has given the correct answer below, so I will just mention the translation mistake that you made.  The sentence is a question, not a statement.  "How should I/one answer/respond on such an occasion?"

Comment: @TokyoNagoya I see the difference. But how do I know the meaning of なんて, as "What/How" as used in a question as above, or "What" used like 「なんて厄介なんだ！」　"What a headache!" (example from space ALC), where the meaning is more like "such" and not asking a question.
(Maybe this should be a new question...)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a contraction of `答えれば`.  More generally, `eba` contracts to `ya`:

```
 kotaereba → kotaerya　　（答えれば　→　答えりゃ）   
     okeba →     okya　　　（おけば　→　　おきゃ）  
      ieba →      iya　　　（言えば　→　　　言や）  
  nakereba →  nakerya　　（なければ　→　なけりゃ）
```

(As you can see, the pattern is easier to see and describe when romanized.)

Comment: I thought なければ becomes なきゃ?

Comment: @user54609 It can!　なければ → なけりゃ → なきゃ

Comment: Just to mention that this also applies to adjectives, as in the example 坊主憎けりゃ袈裟まで憎い, where 憎ければ has become 憎けりゃ.