# 浴びる vs 浴びりゃ-Hikawa Kiyoshi

Tags: pronunciation, slang

I was listening to Hikawa Kiyoshi's ソーラン節 and instead of 浴びる he said 浴びりゃ， is there a normal pattern for this kind of pronunciation? Is it regional?

Comment: Full lyrics [here](http://music.goo.ne.jp/lyric/LYRUTND52655/index.html).

Comment: Also lyrics here a bit easier to search or browse - http://evesta.jp/lyric/artists/a1528/lyrics/l42102.html 
Your question may be related to: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/3169

Answer (score 1):

Song lyrics tend to take poetic license, but if not, this is a shortening of 「浴びれば」. As far as I'm aware, it's not regional, since I hear it in common speech in Tokyo and on television programs.

For more on 「りゃ」see:
http://maggiesensei.com/2011/10/14/%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%EF%BC%89%EF%BC%86%E3%80%80%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83%E3%81%82%EF%BC%89-jaa-ryaa-casual-contraction/

Comment: I don't think a contraction as common as れば -> りゃ falls under "poetic license".