# What does the word 「つなぎゃ」mean?

Tags: words

I found it from the following sentence.

はてね　その先はどう**つなぎゃ**いいんだ。

Comment: See: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「つな**ぎゃ**」 is the colloquial pronunciation of 「つな**げば**」= 「繋げば」

The meaning of the sentence 「はてね　その先はどうつなぎゃいいんだ。」 is highly contextual.

「つなぐ」 can mean "to tie", "to fasten", "to connect", "to keep something going", etc.

I would be inclined to think that it would be about keeping a story/explanation going in a logical manner -- something like **"How should I keep it flowing from here?"** -- but without further context provided, this would be nothing but speculation.

Other examples of ***colloquial conditional forms***:

開{ひら}きゃ、食{た}べりゃ、見{み}りゃ、泳{およ}ぎゃ、行{い}きゃ、いりゃ、ありゃ, etc.