# What is the meaning of 「気のすまぬ」?

Tags: translation, words, particle-の, particle-が, manga

Here is the context including the word.

> なにが　なんでも　たたきのめさにゃ　**気のすまぬ**　男が俺の眼のまえに立ちはだかったんだ。

I found a word 「気がすまない」 in an online dictionary which gives the meaning of it as 'not to be able to settle down (if something is not done)'. I'm not sure that particle 「の」 in the word would make its meaning differs from the one using particle 「が」 instead.

If their meanings are similar, could I translate the whole context like the following sentence?

> There was a guy who blocked my way that I must desperately to beat him down, whatever it takes.

Comment: `たたきのめすにゃ` -> 「たたきのめ**さ**にゃ」ではありませんか？

Comment: related? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Comment: I'm voting this as a duplicate for now, but if you already know about GA-NO conversion and want to ask something more specific, please edit the question and say so.

Comment: @chocolate I would like to reply your first comment. Since the context is hand-written which quite hard for me to interpret,  I thought that it should be 「さ」and I understand that 「にゃ」is a colloquial form of 「には」. However, to use the correct verb form being followed by 「には」is dictionary-form verb, so I think 「たたきのめす」would be the correct one. In this case, please let me know what the meaning of「にゃ」really is.  For the second comment, the link you provided help me answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: たたきのめさにゃ means たたきのめさねば / たたきのめさなければ,  so たたきのめさにゃ気が(orの)済まぬ…  is like たたきのめさなければ気が済まない, "I cannot settle down until I beat him up", "I won't feel happy/satisfied unless I beat him up"

Comment: `nai-form + にゃ(あ)`  ≒ `ねば` ≒ `if not`. See [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/168084/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%83/). Generally, it's ["eba → ya" contraction](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010).