# Meaning of よく見りゃ

Tags: meaning, contractions

> 「だけど成虫になったら、立派なカブトムシになるし、**よく見りゃ**幼虫だってかわいいもんだよ」
>   But if it reaches adulthood it will become a splendid rhinoceros beetle, and even ??? grubs are cute.

My guess is that よく見りゃ means 'good-looking' but I can't find it in any dictionary. Have I guessed correctly? Is it a contraction of something?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12524 ... yoku mireba is idiomatic so I hesitate to say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「見りゃ」＝「見れば」 = "if you look (at it)"

「れば」 is often pronounced 「りゃ」 in informal daily speech.

「よく見りゃ」 thus means "***if you look at it/them carefully***".  It could not mean "good-looking" in any context.