What is 「くりゃあ」a contraction of?
From SAO OVA:

海の中で困ってる人とくりゃあ 人魚と相場が決まってるぜ

What is 「くりゃあ」a contraction of? I know that contractions like this happen a lot (そりゃ, etc.), I just don't know which word this comes from.

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77234/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41477/9831

The phrase is from 'くれば' meaning 'when it comes to something', so the sentence could mean 'When it comes to the person in trouble under the sea, he or she should be a mermaid.
