# Can someone help me with this sentence, please?

Tags: translation, meaning

> もっとも……洞窟の中にいたとしても、冷静に考えりゃ無事にはすまないんだが、それでも外よりはマシだっただろう。

もっとも……洞窟の中にいたとしても would be "Even if you are in the cave..." and それでも外よりはマシだっただろう be "It would be better than being outside".

But I don't understand this part very well: 冷静に考えりゃ無事にはすまないんだが. I know that 冷静に考えりゃ is "thinking calmly", but 無事にはすまない confuses me. I think "すまない" must be another word, because "sorry" doesn't make sense, but I don't recognize it without kanji.

Comment: The gist of it (even w/o context) seems to be: It's reasonable... even if you're inside a cave, if you think about it calmly, you won't get away with it without incident, but even so, it would be better than being outside.

Comment: The two parts are. Part 1: 冷静に考えりゃ: If (you) think calmly. Here reba->rya (the conditional stem). Part 2: 無事にはすまないんだが (It) doesn't come off without a hitch. Negation of buji ni sumu. With explanatory no and daga.

Answer (score 4):

無事 means *safety*, and 済む is a verb that means *to finish*. 無事に済む is a very common set phrase that means *to finish without trouble*. In this case it means something more physical: *to get away without being injured*. 考えりゃ is 考えれば, a colloquial [eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010). This もっとも is something like *admittedly, though*.

So 洞窟の中にいたとしても冷静に考えりゃ無事にはすまない means "even if we had been in the cave, come to think of it calmly, we could not have gotten away without getting injured".