# The meaning of 時点で and すりゃ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

I'm reading a piece of fiction, and I come across this line:

> 確かに面白くはねえだろうが、気付いた時点でリサさんに抗議すりゃいいだけの話だろうが

I'm having troubles understanding what the speaker is saying on two parts -

1) does 時点で refer to the present? So it would always be translated as "this moment in time" rather than "that moment" or "a moment in time". the fact that there is a verb in its past tense before it (気付いた) is confusing me, I'm questioning what moment in time the speaker is referring to, is it now? The past?

2) what does すりゃ mean? Could it be the same as それは?

My best guess at a translations is -

> It's certainly not interesting but I realized at this moment, that you protested against Risa San, that's all it is.

Answer (score 4):

1) 時点 literally means "time point," and here it's modified by a relative clause 気付いた. 気付いた時点で roughly means the same thing as 気付いたときに, "the time (point) when you noticed it", but the former sounds more emphatic ("immediately", "once", ...). If this sentence refers to something in the future, that means this 気付いた is not the past tense but the perfect aspect. (cf. 起きたら電話してください。 Call me once you've gotten up.)

2) すりゃ is colloquialism for すれば. (`-eba` to `-ya` contraction, see: [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010)) It sounds a bit rough and masculine.

> 気付いた時点でリサさんに抗議すりゃいいだけの話だろうが。
>   It's merely the matter of protesting against Risa once you've noticed it, huh?
>   You just have to protest against Risa once you've noticed it.

By the way, that 面白くない is *unpleasant* rather than *uninteresting*.