# たきゃ meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning, translation, slang

The context is as follows:

the player's party wants to cross a bridge and the bandit leader says "何だお前ら？
ここを通りたきゃ通行料1000000G置いてきな！！"

So he wants the characters to pay a toll, but I have trouble understanding the "通りたきゃ" part.

Is it derived from "通りたいなら" or something else?

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of りゃ in this phrase?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/43676), [The meaning of 時点で and すりゃ in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47935/43676)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!