# Meaning of 文句 in the following dialogue

Tags: translation, meaning, words

A ex kick-boxer that now switched to boxing owes money to the yakuza. The following is a dialogue between him and the yakuza man that comes weekly to collect the money (借金取り). 新人王 is the name of a boxing tournament for rookies.

> Yakuza man: お前新人王出んのか…　元キックだって聞いてたが、ボクシングに来たのか。金作るヒマなくて遊ぶ時間はあるのか？
>
> Ex kick-boxer: 登りつめりゃ**文句**ないでしょ？　武器が拳だけのボクシングなんてワケないスから…

I think that what the ex kick-boxer says could be translated into:

> You don't have any objection about me winning (climbing up) the
> tournament, do you? Since boxing is easy as they only use
> punches as weapons...

If I read the question alone I think I understand what it means, but there's から in the second part of the sentence and I don't understand why the first part should be a consequence of the second. What I would find a natural consequence of the second part would be "It will be easy for me to win, right?", but it is too far from the meaning of 文句. Does 文句 refer to an objection by the yakuza man or to something else I am not getting here? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

登りつめりゃ is a contraction of 登りつめれば. See [`eba` to `ya` contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010). This 文句 refers to what was just said by the 借金取り.

Perhaps you failed to read between the lines. He implies:

> You don't have to fuss (about the money and my seemingly bad behavior) *if* I win the tournament (because the champion can get a lot of money), huh? (And I will certainly be the champion) because boxing is easy as they only use punches as weapons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I definitely didn't get the unsaid parts!