# ～てりゃ meaning in this sentence

Tags: grammar, slang

I'm dealing with some TV character's lines that speak in slang, and I don't understand what is the meaning of this "～てりゃ" in the following sentence:

> 適当にやってりゃいいだろう。

Here the context:

There are three girl in a classroom. The first girl tell to the second one that she must act more seriously. Next, the third girl say the line abovementioned, in defense of the second.

I was thinking, may be that "ってりゃ" a simply variation of "ている"? And if it is so, which is its origin? And, have it a special nuance of meaning?

May you help me to understand? Thks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a variant of やってれば:

> 適当にやってればいいだろう。

Similarly to なければ → [なけりゃ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%91%E3%82%8A%E3%82%83)

Comment: But the question is basically [a duplicate](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%82%8a%e3%82%83-in-this-phrase). Will delete it after it gets closed.