# What grammatical strucure is behind 唱えにゃならん and what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

In the sentance below, what is the grammar behind 唱えにゃならん?

> これ小僧や、お前は、いずれはわしの代りにお寺でお経を**唱えにゃならん**のだぞ。

(I thought it was *verb stem+にはならない* with sound changes but I coudn't find such gramatical structure)

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「にゃ」

is a colloquial pronunciation of both:

> 「ねば」 and 「には」

which means you must decide which one it is from the context.

In the phrase:

> 「唱{とな}えにゃならん」

「にゃ」 is short for 「ねば」.  (Grammatically, you cannot say 「唱えには」 in the first place.)

So, the dictionary form of 「唱えにゃならん」 is 「唱えねばならない」, which means the same as 「唱えなければならない」= "***must chant the sutra***" .

> "***Listen, boy, you are going to have to chant the sutra instead of me at the temple one day***."