# 「もらえりゃあいうことない」の意味

Tags: grammar

この下の文章の「もらえりゃあいうことない」の意味がわかりませんでした。

> 例）「そのうえ賞金**もらえりゃあいうことない**なあ。」

この文章の文法を説明していただけませんか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「もらえればああいうことはない」ではないでしょうか……。

Comment: もらえりゃあ is a colloquial way of saying もらえれば.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- りゃ is a colloquial contracted form of れば. See: [`eba`-to-`ya` contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12525/5010).
- あ means almost nothing here, but is added for mild emphasis. It's the same あ after な at the end of this sentence. It has nothing to do with ああ ("that way").
- いうことない is 言うこと**は**ない ("I have nothing to say", "There is nothing to complain").

> そのうえ賞金もらえりゃあいうことないなあ。
>   = そのうえ、賞金もらえれば、言うことはないな。
>   If I can even get a bounty, there is nothing to complain, huh?