# だったらはやくいやあいいのに DB

Tags: translation, contractions

I'm still learning. This is Goku tied to a tree in first chapter of DB.
Translated as: "She should've said it earlier".
Can someone give me a literal translation? Something is preventing me from parsing the sentence right and I think it could provide me the missing link for understanding.

だったら = If that's the case
はやく = soon
いやあ = No / why
いい = say
のに = although

Comment: Related: [eba-to-ya contraction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/5010)

Comment: ^ あらま！「いや」「言えば」で検索してしまったから、見つけられなかったわ・・

Comment: Goku is meant to be a country bumpkin and says a lot of things in a nonstandard way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> いやあ = No / why
>   いい = say

いやあ here is a colloquial pronunciation of [言]{い}えば, which is the conditional form (仮定形) of the verb 言う.
いい is [良]{い}い.

> はやくいやあいいのに

means

> [早]{はや}く[言]{い}えばいいのに。

literally "though it would be good if (she) said soon"
→ (She) should have said it earlier.