# Use of "くれりゃ" in this context

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble with this one.

For context, this is from a manga wherein two characters just ran away from a fight before saying. Also, it's a battle royale.

> 向こうからこっちを狙ってきてくれりゃぁ
>   相手探す手間も省けてちょうど良い

My bad understanding of this is, which is probably wrong is.

"The others are aiming for us too, so if others find that one and saves us the trouble, then great."

Feel free to correct me.

My question is why くれりゃぁ used here? I can't find a good explanation of it online in english. Also, is it something only spoken in a country accent? Because the guy saying it has one.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12524/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%82%8a%e3%82%83-in-this-phrase

Comment: To be clear, the sentence means "If they aim for us, we can save the trouble of finding them, so (it would be) better that way."