# 水着もってくりゃよかった From Dragon Ball Ch3

Tags: translation

Bulma:

> どうせ
>
> こうなるんなら
>
> 水着もってくりゃよかった！
>
> If I knew we were gonna come here, I would have brought my swimsuit

`どうせ In any case`
`こうなる Turn around here`
`ん Nominalizer`
`なら if`
`水着 Swimsuit`
`もって Hold`
`くりゃ Short for きたら?`
`よかった Good`

I couldn't find the くりや ending anywhere. That's my best guess, but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12524/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こうなるんなら = こうなるのならば - if I knew this happens
もってくりゃ = 持ってくれば(持ってきたら) - I should have brought my swimsuit

Comment: `I should bring` ← これも I should have brought (すべきだった(けれど実際はしなかった))のほうが良いのではと思うのですが

Comment: My English sucks still.